# Use gdb to find where program stuck

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

My program is not working correctly.
It looks like it is stuck in an infinite loop or a bad mutex lock/unlock. But, I have no idea where the bug is.
I tried using gdb for debugging.

I can't use gdb backtrace command because I don't designate breakpoint.
And I can't designate it because I don't have any idea where the error is.

**Does gdb have instrument for backtrace "on the fly"?**

Comment: When you think your code is stuck, you can press `Ctrl-C` to break into the debugger, and then show the bactrace, examine variables etc from there.

Comment: `printf` is another debugging method, though not as ideal as using a debugger.

Answer (score 18):

> I can't use gdb backtrace command because I don't designate breakpoint.

Yes, you can.

All you need is for the inferior (being debugged) program to be stopped somewhere.

When you first attach to the program, GDB will stop all threads, and you can examine where they are. Later, you can hit `Ctrl-C`, and again look at all threads. A useful command is `thread apply all where`.

Answer (score 13):

Get the process ID from 'ps -ef' of your program. Use **pstack** to know exactly which function it's hung in. It will print out an execution stack trace.

Example output:

```
$ pstack PROCESS_PID

\#0  0x00000038cfaa664e in waitpid () from /lib64/libc.so.6  
\#1  0x000000000043ed42 in ?? ()  
\#2  0x000000000043ffbf in wait_for ()  
\#3  0x0000000000430bc9 in execute_command_internal ()  
\#4  0x0000000000430dbe in execute_command ()  
\#5  0x000000000041d526 in reader_loop ()  
\#6  0x000000000041ccde in main ()
```