# How can I work around this circular dependency?

Tags: c++

I'm making a sort of indexed list. I have a structure that looks something like this:

```
struct MyList {
    list<Word> records;
    map<char, list<list<Word>::iterator>> index;
    void add_word(Word);
    void erase_by_letter(char&);
};
```

Every time I add a Word to MyList, for every unique character it has I add an iterator on it into "index" map. This way I can quickly access every word that has a letter 'a' in it or letter 'n', etc. But this has an issue: after removing a Word from records every iterator pointing on it in index become invalid. To work around that every Word stores a list of references on it and ~Word() cleans them up on object removal. It looks something like this:

```
struct Word {
   Word(string);
   ~Word();
   vector<pair<list<list<Word>::iterator>*, list<list<Word>::iterator>::iterator>> refs;
   void add_ref(pair<list<list<Word>::iterator>*, list<list<Word>::iterator>::iterator>);
   void clean_refs();
   string value;
};
```

So. All of that works fine so far. To my rookie eye it doesn't look like a good design but I could live with that. The problem is GDB can't. I use VS Code + GDB and every time debugger comes anywhere near this structure it stops responding. My guess is it goes into an endless loop because an entry in *index* points to *Word* in *records* and *Word* itself has inside *refs* vector that points back to *index* entry and so on and on so poor debugger just stares into abyss.

Two questions:

1. Can I make GDB to stop looking too deep into this loop or maybe detect it and give up on it?
2. How should I implement this properly to avoid circular references?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use gdb to find where program stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810662/use-gdb-to-find-where-program-stuck)

Comment: @jjramsey thank you, but no. My problem is actually the opposite: the program works, I have an issue with debugger stucking when looking into it.

Comment: Your problem is likely in your removeWord() function. Please add its code. Also, before thinking about optimizing your code with so much cross references, you should first make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get back to the original problem : invalid iterators **when** a word is deleted.

First of all, I'd have removed all the reference stuff you have configured into your Word struct in order to get back to a clean state.

So now, we have this :

```
struct Word
{
   Word(string);
   ~Word();
   
   string value;
};
```

Now, let's go on your struct MyList.
As you explained, the problem is the invalid iterators you have **after** deleting a word pointing at it.

Here is my proposal :

In the delete method you use to delete a word from MyList, before deleting the Word in question, **1.** iterate over MyList and get the iterator pointing to your Word.

Then, **2.** parse your map of iterators and delete the iterators which are the same than in step **1.**.

Finally, **3.** delete your word From MyList.

Comment: I mean, I want to have an index to speed up things, the option of removing words in batches was the whole point of it. I think parsing through the map every time a word is deleted is going to be slow, it invalidates the purpose. This code is supposed to run milliards times through the lifetime of the program.

Comment: @ambercloud got it. So instead, what if you implement a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<List<Word>::iterator>> within the Word struct ? In MyList, you could be working with all the unique_ptr instead of the iterators. Those smart pointers would die anyway when a Word is deleted from the list, so the only check you'd have to do is on the smart ptr value to be nullptr or not.

Comment: I was thinking in this direction and left it as a backup plan. My idea was a bit different: using list<shared_ptr<Word>> for records and map<char, vector<weak_ptr<Word>>> for index. I'm not sure about it though, haven't tried working with smart pointers yet, I've only started learning c++ recently.